# Convert &#char(w); to \uxxxx C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I am working on Korean Document and the HTML Source Code contains special symbols starting with &#char(w) e.g 껰 Now I would like to convert this symbol to its Unicode represntation.

Is there a way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the codepoint by converting it to `int`. Then, use `String.Format` to obtain the Unicode code string:

```
string result = string.Format("\\u{0:x4}", (int) chr);
```

or:

```
string result = "\\u" + ((int) chr).ToString("x4");
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML uses the &# and &#x notation to encode Unicode characters. So your document already contains the charcters in one possible Unicode notation.

If the sequence starts with &#x the following characters are the hex code of the character. If the sequence starts with &# the following numbers are the decimal code of the character.

Convert these code to hex using ToString("x4") as in Konrad's answer.